# TextChanged event is not firing in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, textchanged

In the below code i have been working on asp.net web application .in my case the textchange event is not firing.Pls help me to solve the issue.
code:

```
public delegate void LeavingFocusHandler(int CurrentIndex);
public event LeavingFocusHandler LeavingFocus;

public string strValue { get; set; } 
public int ItemIndex { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtField.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtField_Leave);
}

void txtField_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.strValue = txtField.Text;

        if (this.LeavingFocus != null)
        {
            this.LeavingFocus(this.ItemIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Design code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextChanged event function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029804/textchanged-event-function-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` to do the postback. You better do not do that as It may cause unnecessary postbacks.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Is it possible when textchanged in the textbox it should move to that method.

Comment: Typing into a textbox will not fire the postback, only when you exit the control.

You could use a client side "onclick" eventhandler that then initiates a "__doPostback" but this would put quite a significant overhead on typing as you would block the user typing whilst the postback was running.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chris Hammond when user types in the text box and leave the focus it should move to that method txtField_Leave

Comment: So what you are saying is that you need to do something as soon as you leave the text box, then you need to add `AutoPostBack="true"`.  I am not sure you would then need to bind specific event handlers as ASP.Net will automatically issue a postback for you

Answer (score 0):

Move the event binding line

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        this.txtField.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtField_Leave);
    }
```

to the page oninit event handler.

Comment: when i debug it is not firing the textchange event

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

You need to set AutoPostBack property to True for firing TextChange event

> Design code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

> Code Behind

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
    {
        this.strValue = txtField.Text;

        if (this.LeavingFocus != null)
        {
            this.LeavingFocus(this.ItemIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: what event has to set for this  TextBox1_TextChanged